# goog.event.listen resize event not received from jquery

Tags: jquery, dom-events, window-resize, google-closure

I use a JS library (GoXTK.com). It uses `goog.event.listen` to resize a canvas if needed:

```
goog.events.listen(window, goog.events.EventType.RESIZE, this.onResize_,
      false, this);
```

It works well if I modify the size of my window with my mouse.

However, sometimes I just want to trigger this callback without actually resizing the window. To do so, I want to use jQuery:

```
$(window).resize();
```

In this case, the `goog` callback is not triggered again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to dispatch event:

```
var ev = document.createEvent('Event');
ev.initEvent('resize', true, true);
window.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: That works great. Could you tell more about it? What was wrong and why this one works? Thansk

Comment: @Nicolas using `$(window).resize();` you were trying to trigger jQuery  handler. This plugin you are using (i don't know it) seems to attach event using javscript native method addEventListener. Then to trigger this handler, you need to dispatch event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent

Comment: @A-wolf OK that make sense thanks, I thought jQuery would dispatch it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `goog.events` package to dispatch the event :

http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_events_events.js.source.html#line786

This particular scenario was brought up in this forum :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/cEtEsx_M42o

If you read through it you will see that goog.events.dispatchEvent expects an `EventTarget` object, so you need to extend the Window dom object :

```
var googWin = window;
    goog.inherits(googWin, goog.events.EventTarget);
    goog.events.dispatchEvent(window, goog.events.EventType.RESIZE);
```

(Note I am just pulling that solution from the forum response, so I have not personally verified it working)